# Run a scheduled Azure PHP script on each instance

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, scheduler, azure-webjobs

We have a website running on multiple Azure instances – typically between 2 and 5.

There is a PHP script I would like to schedule to run every few minutes on each instance. (It just makes a local copy of data from a system that couldn't handle the load from all our users hitting it in real-time.)

If it were just one instance, that would be easy - I'd use Azure Scheduler to call *www.example.com/my-scheduled-task.php* every 5 minutes.

But the script needs to run on **each** instance, so that every instance has a reasonably up-to-date copy of the data. How would you achieve this? I can't work out if it's something in Azure Scheduler, or if I should be looking at some sort of startup script?

Comment: Can you clarify what specific Azure technology you are using? Is it an Azure Web App, or an Azure Cloud Service?

Comment: Hi David, we run on Azure Web Apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a continuous webjob for that.

Just tweak your php script to have a loop and add a sleep of a few minutes between runs of your code.

The continuous webjob will run on all of your instances and even if somethings fails it will be brought back up.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Per my experience, a PHP webjob running on your each webapp instance is the good solution as @AmitApple said. However, I think you can try to use a scheduled webjob with a CRON expression for ensuring a start time, not a continuous one with a sleep time. And please make sure the script can be completed in the interval time.</del>

<del>You can refer to [the section `Create a scheduled WebJob using a CRON expression` of the doc `Run Background tasks with WebJobs`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON) to know how to get start.</del>

Please see the note of the section `Create a continuously running WebJob` https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateContinuous.

> **Note:**
>
> If your web app runs on more than one instance, a continuously running WebJob will run on all of your instances. On-demand and scheduled WebJobs run on a single instance selected for load balancing by Microsoft Azure.
>
> For Continuous WebJobs to run reliably and on all instances, enable the Always On* configuration setting for the web app otherwise they can stop running when the SCM host site has been idle for too long.

Comment: The issue with this approach is it won't run on all instances, just on one.

Comment: @AmitApple Sure. If the web app runs on more than one instance, a continuously running WebJob will run on all instances at once. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks heaps, Peter! This is really useful info.